# andengine livewallpaper doesn't react on the provided ResolutionPolicy

Tags: java, android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to use CroppedResolutionPolicy from this topic http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/targeting-multiple-display-resolutions-t6794.html. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        this.cameraWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        this.cameraHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        this.camera = CameraFactory.createPixelPerfectCamera(this, this.cameraWidth / 2.0F, this.cameraHeight / 2.0F);
        this.camera.setResizeOnSurfaceSizeChanged(true);
        this.dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

        CroppedResolutionPolicy croppedResolutionPolicy = new CroppedResolutionPolicy(this.cameraWidth, this.cameraHeight);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR, croppedResolutionPolicy, this.camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
        return engineOptions;
}
```

but I noticed that method CroppedResolutionPolicy.onMeasure never calls. 
I debugged it on my HTC Sensation.

It seems that andengine livewallpaper doesn't react on the provided ResolutionPolicy at all.. At least on my HTC

How to correctly apply CroppedResolutionPolicy in my wallpaper ? Thanks !